# find nearest td inside element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my code,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".mail").on("click",function(){
alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.td_class div').attr('var'));
});
});
</script>
<table><tr>
<td class='td_class'><div var='value'></div></td>
<td><div class='mail'>click</div></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
```

okay, I wanna alert 'value' that is div's attribute var...
but it's not working help me...
thank you.

Comment: you missed `''` for `.td_class div` other than that it looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ab9fr7eh/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed quotes for `find(.td_class div)`

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".mail").on("click",function(){
          alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.td_class div').attr('var'));
       });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: i given the quotes but it alerts 'undefined'

Comment: It is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/spt9k6qh/12/ ... see if there are any console error present... or share jsfiddle link to me. Also don't forget to remove `^------^` from my script

Answer (score 1):

in this particular case

```
var x = $(this).parent().prev().find('>div').attr('var');
alert(x);
```